# Manga where the main character wears an eyepatch (that can sprout legs) over a golden eye

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don’t remember much, besides the character being a male and growing up in a poor village of sorts. And he has a golden eye but it is covered with an eyepatch that is sort of like a bug. It grows legs and pops off when he needs the power.

In the first couple of chapters his village elders and his mentor (well, mostly his mentor) set up a plot to get him to unleash his powers. So he ends up making it seem like he kidnapped the elders and the main character goes down in to a basement of sorts to fight with him, and he eventually unleashes his power and the bug/patch grows off and goes to hide.

Comment: @Valorum I think your edit on the title "over a bug-like eye" conflicted with the OP's description "an eyepatch that is sort of like a bug". I interpreted the MC has normal golden eyes and a bug-like eyepatch (the last sentence "bug/patch" proves even more), not a bug-like eye covered with an eyepatch.

Comment: @AndrewT. - I've fixed it. Don't forget that you can use the edit button as well if you think an improvement can be made ;-)

Comment: Can't find this on TV Tropes so far

Comment: @Sinba is it that the eyepatch grows legs, or that the eye grows legs?

Comment: @Stormblessed Neither could I. The only reference I found to a moving eyepatch was in *Bleach*, and the character with said eyepatch a) isn't the main character, and b) doesn't have a golden eye. I've got this favourited in case I stumble across it later.

Comment: @Stormblessed this is only my assumption (since the unregistered OP doesn't seem to return soon), but I guess it's the eyepatch that looks like a bug and grows legs.

Answer (score 3):

It’s been a while but I have finally found it. It’s called *10 Prism*.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/72451/Ten_Prism):

> The story revolves around Tsunashi, the child of royalty who was left behind in the lost kingdom of Karan. He is expected by those around him to awaken his great powers that sleep within him in order to revive the kingdom—but rather than fighting, Tsunashi enjoys playing in the world of books. However, he must become serious soon, as a new army is threatening to invade Karan.

[image: character with a big sword, kneeling and with a hand over his eye]

It’s great y’all should give it a read!

Comment: You can merge your accounts by following the instructions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts); please do so. This way, you'll be able to formally accept that answer.